# Remove all text after line with [info]

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to remove all lines of text after a single line of text "[info]" Here is an example:

```
Top=1266
[info]
name=tod
space=456
number=221,441,111,0
[version]
version=1
```

I only need the top, the other text will be replaced later on in the script. Here is all that I have tried

```
$Content -replace '\[Info\]*',''
```

Only removes the Info line and not anything past that. I have tried to loop, but I can't seem to find the line with a where object search.

What is a quick and easy way to remove all lines of code after a single line of set text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the `-replace` operator treat it as one string, add `(?s)` to the pattern.

```
$Content -replace '(?s)\[Info\].*'
```

You also needed to match any character so `.*` works in this case. The second part is optional. Since you're replacing it with nothing you can simply omit it.

Read more about regular expression in powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1

and operators

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Nice; to spell it out: The `s` inline regex option makes `.` match _newlines_ (line breaks) as well.